# google_maps_flutter cost for google map usage

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-flutter

I am investigating possibility of using Flutter for a new version of our app which initially will encompass a subset of features, but soon we will migrate all our current app's features to replace it. Our current app is native Android and iOS.

One thing we have is the map views on the app. We have millions of users using the app everyday, so I need to identify if we're going to have issues adopting map views on flutter.

I found this plugin for flutter: https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter

This would work for us, but I need to work out whether it would cost us extra $. For bot map usage and iOS and Android it appears that map usage for mobile native dynamic maps is free:
[image: Snippet from page]

Do maps loaded with flutter fall under the category of Mobile Native Dynamic Apps or Dynamic Apps? We do not use map ID.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Still no answers it seems unfortunate :( , I am Asking the same question. Don't mind me follow this question.

Comment: Same here, commenting so that I can be notified if someone answers